# How to have a multi-file emacs package?

Tags: package

Perhaps a beginner question, but I couldn't find a recommended way to split a package to multiple files. It's still a single package, just part of code is in a different file (so no `(provide 'sub-feature)` required).

Emacs Lisp manual's [42.3 Multi-file Packages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Multi_002dfile-Packages.html) mentions `load-file-name`, but that is `nil` while developing.

Comment: Actually, all the examples I know (`ivy` for instance) use precisely the `require` and `provide` mechanism.  There is no rule that says a package must have only one feature!

Comment: @FranBurstall Right, but the second file doesn't provide any new features, it's just a set of helper functions used in the main file.

Comment: I guess the require/provide conflates package and modules in other languages? so if provide provides *modules* then it would make sense to use the require/provide mechanism as it's essentially a second module in the same package.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: require/provide predate packages (in the elpa sense) and so can be thought of as a mechanism for modules.